# Can someone explain how Sims's algorithm works on a permutation group with a simple example?

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

Can someone explain how Sims's algorithm works on a permutation group with a simple example? The book "Permutation group algorithms" by Seress is a pretty hard read with a whole bunch of confusing notation.

Comment: This is not exactly a research question is it?

Comment: @DerekHolt No, but Sims' algorithm is not known to so many people outside a reasonably small community of which you are a member. Now that I see your name, I realize that I should have mentioned the handbook of which you are the author, but I am guessing that a BSc thesis would be a little easier going.

Comment: @IgorRivin  I would not claim that the Handbook is any easier to read than Seress' book. They are both perfectly readable, and the notation is generally necessary and appropriate.

Comment: “If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself.” -Albert Einstein

Comment: I definetly think Holt's book is better than the Seress book however I still cant find a simple and concrete example of sim's table so I can go back to the notation and see the generic structure. Sometimes it is just hard to go from notation to example!

Comment: @user1870400 That use of Einstein's line is pure sophistry, as you should know if you teach maths

Comment: @YemonChoi Doesn't matter how you take it! After all, it just your opinion! The Quote is there for good reasons!

Comment: Note for anyone else reading the comment thread: this question has since been posted on MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662723/ where @DerekHolt has given what looks to be a perfectly decent answer

Answer (score 2):

Read [Murray's BSc essay from Sydney (2003)](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/murray/research/essay.pdf)